# PHP SESSION HTML table carrying issue

Tags: php

I am adding items to my cart.php using an add in the URL.

```
    case "add":
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])) {
$_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]++;
} else {
$_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id] = 1;}
```

... My items are presented into an HTML table in the cart.php. I just want to then re-call specific variables from the array in the checkout.php so the customer can confirm the order total along with their personal details.

I can only seem to carry the last added item/row over using SESSION variable when I use the following:

```
$_SESSION['totalnameqty']=$name . " " . $qty . " " . $cost;
```

...and then use an echo on the checkout.php page:

```
$totnamqty=$_SESSION['totnamqty'];
echo $totnamqty;
```

... I want to carry all items $name, $qty & $cost added to the HTML table in the cart.php to the checkout.php not just 1 item/row. Unsure of how to do this or if it is possible. Can somebody help?

Here is my cart.php:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id])){

    echo "<table border=\"0\" padding=\"10\" width=\"80%\">";
    echo "<td colspan=\"1\" align=\"left\"><a href=\"title.php\">Continue Shopping</a></div>";
    echo "<td colspan=\"6\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Crystal Fusion: Are you sure you wish to empty your cart?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";                  
    echo "<tr height=\"20px\">";
    echo "<tr height=\"20px\">"; 
    echo "<td align=center>Image</td><td align=center>Title</td><td align=center>Description</td><td colspan=3 align=center>Copies (+/-)</td><td align=center>Price</td>";
    echo "<tr height=\"20px\">";


    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $comic_id => $qty) {   

        $sql = sprintf("SELECT title, description, cost, image_thumbnail
                FROM comic 
                WHERE comic_id = %d;",$comic_id); 

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            list($name, $description, $price, $image_thumbnail) = mysql_fetch_row($result);


            $cost = $price * $qty; 
            $total = $total + $cost; 

            $cost = number_format($cost,2); 
            $total = number_format($total,2); 
            $description =  substr($description, 0, 250); 

            echo "<br><tr>";
            echo "<td width=\"10px\" align=\"center\"><img height=100 align=center src=\"$image_thumbnail\">";
            echo "<td align=\"center\">$name</td>";
            echo "<td width=\"40%\" align=\"center\">$description...<a href=comic_dyn.php?comic_id=$comic_id>More Info</td>";
            echo "<td width=\"30px\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=add&comic_id=$comic_id\">+<br></a><td align=\"center\">$qty <td width=\"20px\" align=\"center\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&comic_id=$comic_id\">-</a></td>";
            echo "<td align=\"right\">$$cost</td>";
            echo "</tr>";           
        }

    }

    echo "<br><tr><tr height=100px>";
    echo "<td><td><td colspan=\"4\" align=\"right\">Total:</td>";
    echo "<td width=\"60px\" align=\"right\">$$total</td>"; 
    echo "<tr><td colspan=\"7\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"checkout_html.php\">Proceed to Checkout</a>"; 
    echo "<tr height=\"50px\">";
    echo "</table>";
}else{

    echo "Your cart is currently empty."; 
    echo "<br><br><td colspan=\"1\" align=\"left\"><a href=\"title.php\">Continue Shopping</a></div>"; 

}

//session variables (to be carried to checkout.php
$_SESSION['cost']=$cost;
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
$_SESSION['qty']=$qty;
$_SESSION['totnamqty']=$name . " " . $qty . " " . $cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting $name, $qty and $cost values inside a loop, therefore you are accessing the last set values below/outside of the loop.  Also, you're using $comic_id at the beginning but below are using that same variable in your foreach statement.  I'm guessing you can remove the foreach and instead use: $qty = $_SESSION['cart'][$comic_id]?

Otherwise, assuming the isset() at the top is incorrect, and that you are trying to loop each $comic_id from the cart; then you want to index your 'cost', 'name', 'qty' and 'tonamqty' values per $comic_id.  eg. use something like this inside your foreach loop: $_SESSION['comics'][$comic_id]['cost'] = $cost;

However, I think a checkout approach without using session variables is more appropriate.  I'd post what the user currently sees to checkout.php, rather than using the session data.  Assume the session was accessed from multiple tabs and the user clicks checkout on an outdated tab.  If using session variables, the server is only aware that the user requested to checkout the most recent items in the session, not what was actively visible.